# SQL joins not giving me correct totals

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to get a report for figures from multiple transaction tables. Each table has a foreign key that is a lookup for the day it was taken on, and what location it was taken at called `Site_Lookup_Id`. It's giving me  figures that are much larger than they should be.

```
@Site_Lookup_Ids dbo.Id_List READONLY

SELECT SL.Site_Lookup_Id, D.[Start],SUM(I.Amount) AS Income, 
       SUM(P.Amount) AS Payouts,SUM(DP.Amount) AS Deposit 
FROM CashUp_Site_Lookup SL
INNER JOIN @Site_Lookup_Ids IDs ON Ids.Id = SL.Site_Lookup_Id
INNER JOIN CashUp_Day D ON SL.Day_Id = D.Day_Id
LEFT JOIN CashUp_Deposit DP ON DP.Redeemed_Site_Lookup_Id = SL.Site_Lookup_Id 
                            AND DP.No_Show != 1
LEFT JOIN CashUp_Income I ON I.Site_Lookup_Id = SL.Site_Lookup_Id
LEFT JOIN CashUp_Payout P ON P.Site_Lookup_Id = SL.Site_Lookup_Id
GROUP BY SL.Site_Lookup_Id, D.[Start]
```

Not all sums will have a value as some days no transactions for a given table will be taken on the day - In this the value should be zero.

The issue is that running this gives me crazy high values - £7500 for income against one day, when if I do a simple check it's £40 for that day like so.

```
SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM Cashup_Income WHERE Site_Lookup_Id IN (values...)
```

Comment: This is because of the 1:M relationships between your tables; either you have missing join criteria or you need to do the aggregation on the table before the joins or use window functions to sum partitioning by the key of the table having the amount.

Comment: @xQbert So I need to use a nested select for each table to essentially get an inner result, then join that on the outer select?

Comment: That's one way to do it yes.  common table expressions would be another, and possibly window functions would be a 3rd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like...

It really depends on the relationships and when you want the values to be summed.

```
SELECT SL.Site_Lookup_Id
     , D.[Start]
     , SUM(I.Amount) over (partition by Key of I table) AS Income
     , SUM(P.Amount) over (partition by Key of P table) AS Payouts
     , SUM(DP.Amount) over (partition by Key of DP Table) AS Deposit 
FROM CashUp_Site_Lookup SL
INNER JOIN @Site_Lookup_Ids IDs ON Ids.Id = SL.Site_Lookup_Id
INNER JOIN CashUp_Day D ON SL.Day_Id = D.Day_Id
LEFT JOIN CashUp_Deposit DP ON DP.Redeemed_Site_Lookup_Id = SL.Site_Lookup_Id 
                            AND DP.No_Show != 1
LEFT JOIN CashUp_Income I ON I.Site_Lookup_Id = SL.Site_Lookup_Id
LEFT JOIN CashUp_Payout P ON P.Site_Lookup_Id = SL.Site_Lookup_Id
GROUP BY SL.Site_Lookup_Id, D.[Start]
```

The problem stems from the fact that your tables are 1:M  Causing values to repeat.  These repeated values are then getting added to your sum.  The joins cause this issue.  So I think you can sum using a partition to eliminate the duplicates or:

Use derived tables or a CTE and sum the values BEFORE you join.

Using CTE's (Common Table Expressions)

```
WITH DP AS (SELECT sum(Amount) As Deposit 
                 , Redeemed_Site_Lookup_ID
            FROM CashUp_Deposit
            WHERE No_Show !=1
            GROUP BY Redeemed_Site_Lookup_ID),
     I  AS (SELECT sum(Amount) as Income
                 , Site_Lookup_Id 
            FROM CashUp_Income 
            GROUP BY Site_Lookup_Id),
     P AS (SELECT sum(Amount) as Payouts
                 , Site_Lookup_Id 
            FROM CashUp_Payout 
            GROUP BY Site_Lookup_Id)

SELECT SL.Site_Lookup_Id
     , D.[Start]
     , Income
     , Payouts
     , Deposit 
FROM CashUp_Site_Lookup SL
INNER JOIN @Site_Lookup_Ids IDs 
        ON Ids.Id = SL.Site_Lookup_Id
INNER JOIN CashUp_Day D 
        ON SL.Day_Id = D.Day_Id
LEFT JOIN DP 
       ON DP.Redeemed_Site_Lookup_Id = SL.Site_Lookup_Id 
LEFT JOIN I 
       ON I.Site_Lookup_Id = SL.Site_Lookup_Id
LEFT JOIN P 
       ON P.Site_Lookup_Id = SL.Site_Lookup_Id
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you are generating a Cartesian product with your joins.  Because you have no filtering, do the aggregation *before* the `join`s:

```
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT DP.Redeemed_Site_Lookup_Id, SUM(DP.Amount) AS Deposit 
 FROM CashUp_Deposit DP
 WHERE DP.No_Show != 1
 GROUP BY DP.Redeemed_Site_Lookup_Id
) DP
ON DP.Redeemed_Site_Lookup_Id = SL.Site_Lookup_Id LEFT JOIN
(SELECT I.Site_Lookup_Id, SUM(I.Amount) AS Income
 FROM CashUp_Income I
 GROUP BY I.Site_Lookup_Id
) I
ON I.Site_Lookup_Id = SL.Site_Lookup_Id LEFT JOIN
(SELECT P.Site_Lookup_Id, SUM(P.Amount) AS Payout
 FROM CashUp_Payout P
 GROUP BY I.Site_Lookup_Id
) P
ON P.Site_Lookup_Id = SL.Site_Lookup_Id
```

Then adjust the rest of your query to remove the `GROUP BY` and `SUM()`s.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, upvoted but accepted the earlier answer as it gives me correct result also

Comment: @SeanT . . . The answer that preceded this one used window functions, and this is definitely superior to that.  The edited version is essentially this version with CTEs rather than subqueries.